# Put separate block tag inside other separate block tag in child template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have base template with page title and Open Graph meta

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>

<meta property="og:title" content="{% block og-title %}{% endblock %}">
```

In my child template i want to set both `title` and `og-title` to same value. I want use only templates, and avoid duplication of title value.

I can put `og-title` block inside `title` block to achieve this.

child.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}{% block og-title %}{% endblock %}{% endblock %}
```

This works as i expect for Django 1.8.4. But the question is how long it will remain working solution? Is it a kind of dirty hack, that could stop working in feature?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [django-capture-tag](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-capture-tag/) to capture title block value:

```
<title>{% capture as meta_title %}{% block title %}{% endblock %}{% endcapture %}</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="{{ meta_title  }}">
```